# Reaching EOF before end of file on windows

Tags: c, file-io, jpeg, eof, fat32

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int size = 512;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    unsigned char buffer[size];
    int count = 0;
    FILE *jpeg = NULL;

    while(fread(buffer, size, 1, file))
    {
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            char image[7];
            if (count != 0)
            {
                fclose(jpeg);
            }
            sprintf(image, "%03i.jpg", count);
            jpeg = fopen(image, "w");
            if (jpeg == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "couldn't open file\n");
                return 1;
            }
            count++;
        }
        if (count != 0)
        {
            fwrite(&buffer, size, 1, jpeg);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);

}
```

This code look for jpeg in card.raw When i run above code on linux, its running correctly. but on windows code reads only first three block of 512 bytes of card.raw file.
what i'm doing wrong?
also i'm using clang on linux. and on windows i'm using gcc.

Comment: `fopen(argv[1], "r")` -> `fopen(argv[1], "rb")`

Comment: I already tried this but still same problem.

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but shouldn't `fread(buffer, size, 1, file)` be `fread(buffer, 1, size, file)`?

Comment: Still same problem

Comment: `char image[7]; sprintf(image, "%03i.jpg", count);` Oops, out-of-range access!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, binary files should be opened with binary mode. This means you should use `"rb"` and `"wb"` for `fopen()` mode instead of `"r"` and `"w"`. Otherwise, newline characters may be unwantedly converted and they may stop at byte `0x1a`.

Secondly, doing `sprintf(image, "%03i.jpg", count);` for the array `char image[7];` is bad. The result of `sprintf()` will be (at least) 7 characters, so array with 8 elements or more is required to store the string including terminating null-character. for safety, you should use [`snprintf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf), which accepts the buffer size.

Comment: i'm new so i was struggling with this from 2 days.